# Display local actions only on nodes of given type

Tags: nodes, actions

I have defined a local action in `my_module.links.action.yml`.
I have defined, that it should be displayed on a single route `appears_on: entity.node.canonical`. - And it works fine.

Now I try to achieve, that the local action only will be displayed on nodes of type `page`.

How can I manage this clean within the Drupal API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to block access to the route for other content types

In your `routing.yml`

```yml
my_module.node_custom_action:
  path: '/node/{node}/custompath'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\my_module\Form\CustomActionForm'
    _title: 'Do custom stuff'
  options:
    _node_operation_route: TRUE
    parameters:
      node:
        type: entity:node
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\my_module\Form\CustomActionForm::isAllowedAccess'
```

In your Form (or Controller)

```php
  public function isAllowedAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
    $bundle = FALSE;
    $route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
    $node = $route->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
      $bundle = $node->bundle();
      if (!$node->access('update', $account)) {
        return AccessResult::neutral();
      }
      return AccessResult::allowedIf($bundle === 'my_content_type');
    }
    return AccessResult::neutral();
  }
```

[Source](https://peacocksoftware.com/blog/drupal-89-views-tab-only-certain-node-types)